# +30 sites using 1gb ram on nginx

Tags: server, webserver, nginx, vps

I have a LEMP setup (Ubuntu 12.04, Nginx, Mysql, PHP 5.3 and APC) and I have 30 sites hosted on it. They all are wordpress sites. It uses about 1GB RAM. Is this normal? I thought nginx would use less ram than apache would. Each site only receive about 200 hits daily

This is the top

```
top - 04:46:39 up 12:27,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.00
Tasks:  40 total,   1 running,  39 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4194304k total,   788356k used,  3405948k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      15   0  2496 1404 1168 S    0  0.0   0:00.29 init
 1179 root      15   0  2328  896  712 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 cron
 1241 mysql     15   0  158m  48m 5968 S    0  1.2   5:33.31 mysqld
 1271 syslog    15   0  2456 1216  548 S    0  0.0   0:00.06 syslogd
 1320 root      18   0  5496 2124 1712 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
 1341 root      25   0  5832 1736  292 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 nginx
 1342 www-data  18   0  6300 2892  892 S    0  0.1   0:02.54 nginx
 1343 www-data  18   0  6332 2840  884 S    0  0.1   0:02.48 nginx
 1345 www-data  18   0  6300 2840  884 S    0  0.1   0:02.39 nginx
 1347 www-data  15   0  6300 2848  892 S    0  0.1   0:01.98 nginx
 1349 root      18   0  539m 4252 1452 S    0  0.1   0:00.01 php-fpm
 1441 root      17   0  5764 1760 1404 S    0  0.0   0:00.03 master
 1449 postfix   18   0  5916 1868 1472 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 qmgr
 1455 snmp      18   0  8688 3772 2160 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 snmpd
 1504 root      23   0  2448  876  700 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 xinetd
 3144 root      18   0  4360 1332  996 S    0  0.0   0:00.08 ntpd
 5708 www-data  16   0  554m 125m 108m S    0  3.1   0:03.50 php-fpm
 5709 www-data  15   0  553m 118m 101m S    0  2.9   0:02.51 php-fpm
 5710 www-data  15   0  559m 134m 110m S    0  3.3   0:03.25 php-fpm
 5711 www-data  15   0  548m 103m  90m S    0  2.5   0:02.39 php-fpm
 5712 www-data  15   0  543m 117m 110m S    0  2.9   0:02.86 php-fpm
 5713 www-data  15   0  542m  93m  87m S    0  2.3   0:02.16 php-fpm
 5714 www-data  15   0  546m 108m  99m S    0  2.7   0:01.88 php-fpm
 5715 www-data  15   0  559m  92m  69m S    0  2.3   0:02.29 php-fpm
 5720 www-data  15   0  555m 128m 110m S    0  3.1   0:03.24 php-fpm
 5721 www-data  16   0  542m 101m  95m S    0  2.5   0:03.63 php-fpm
 5722 www-data  15   0  548m 101m  89m S    0  2.5   0:02.81 php-fpm
 5723 www-data  15   0  556m  94m  74m S    0  2.3   0:02.96 php-fpm
 5726 www-data  15   0  554m  93m  75m S    0  2.3   0:03.43 php-fpm
 5727 www-data  15   0  542m  93m  87m S    0  2.3   0:02.03 php-fpm
 5728 www-data  15   0  546m  97m  87m S    0  2.4   0:03.56 php-fpm
 5729 www-data  15   0  552m 131m 115m S    0  3.2   0:02.40 php-fpm
 5751 www-data  16   0  544m  91m  83m S    0  2.2   0:02.29 php-fpm
 5752 www-data  15   0  547m 104m  93m S    0  2.6   0:02.85 php-fpm
 5753 www-data  15   0  556m 110m  90m S    0  2.7   0:01.59 php-fpm
 5754 www-data  15   0  549m  94m  81m S    0  2.3   0:01.97 php-fpm
 5796 postfix   18   0  5780 1676 1340 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 pickup
 5797 root      15   0  8304 2796 2224 S    0  0.1   0:00.05 sshd
 5808 root      18   0  3136 1784 1320 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
 5819 root      18   0  2368 1112  892 R    0  0.0   0:00.00 top
```

Comment: use top to see what exactly is using your RAM.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal to see 1 GB usage for 30 WordPress sites without a caching layer. For sites with a caching layer and with most visitors are not logged-in, it is not normal.

In most cases, it is not Nginx, but php-fpm and MySQL that use more memory than Nginx. Of course, Nginx is more efficient than Apache. While *top* is useful, you may use [this scirpt](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py) to find which process uses how much memory. Please know that *ps_mem.py* requires 'root' or 'sudo' privilege.

If you'd like to reduce the memory usage, you may use a caching layer, such as [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/). Alternatively, you may use application level caching, such as [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) or [Batcache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/batcache/) (both work fine with APC as WP Object Cache). I hope that helps.